# Accessing web server using HTTP Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to access a php file located on a web server using AsyncTask and the Default Http Client.

I keep getting this error:

**Unable to resolve host "hostname": No address associated with hostname**

This is my Activity where I try to access it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new HTTPTask().execute();
        }
    });
}

private class HTTPTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        //location of file to retrieve
        String url = "http://hostname/12345/db_connect.php";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            httpclient.execute(httppost);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in Connection " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Established!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection initiating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

}

I've also added the following to my manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I just can't think what it could be? I am working off a machine in my college, I am guessing it might be the security in the building? Any help is much appreciated!

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dbconnectiontest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: add here your full manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution

Hope it will solve your problem.

add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, just after the `<manifest>` tag and before the `<application>` tag:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**EDIT :**

if it not working then the most common cause of this `UnknownHostException error message`. Another possible cause is that your internet connection is actually down, and you can test that with the "`ping`" command.

Comment: I pinged the host and It sent the 4 packets successfully. I wonder is it something to do with my Campus security, It's a web server located on the campus you see

Comment: I just changed the url to www.google.com and no error, connection was established successfully. I will have to speak to IT department tomorrow to sort out the problem. Thanks for the help Dixit!